# Using pandas, write a custom function applied to DataFrame group to calculate average step

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
               'c2': [3,3,3,4,4,4],
               'code': [1,2,3,1,2,3],
               'd1': [100,101,102,103,104,105],
               'd2': [200,201,202,203,204,205],})
```

It looks like this:

```
    c1  c2  code    d1  d2
0   a   3   1   100 200
1   a   3   2   101 201
2   a   3   3   102 202
3   b   4   1   103 203
4   b   4   2   104 204
5   b   4   3   105 205
```

I am going to group it by 'c1' and 'c2', then I want to calculate the average step for 'd1' and 'd2'. So for the first group(c1='a' and c2='3'), the average step is calculated as (102-100)/(3-1)=1.

Eventually I want to output something like this:

```
    c1  c2 d1_step d2_step
    a   3   1      1
    b   4   1      1
```

I learned that I can use groupby() and apply(func) to perform some functions to the group object. How this func be written?

Comment: Show us what you have tried (you can read: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation if you don't know where to start)

Comment: @jim.l if any of the answers below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
step_size = df.set_index(['c1', 'c2']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).diff(2).dropna()
step_rate = step_size[['d1', 'd2']].div(step_size.code, axis=0)
step_rate
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                   'c2': [3,3,3,4,4,4],
                   'code': [1,2,3,1,2,3],
                   'd1': [100,101,102,103,104,105],
                   'd2': [200,201,202,203,204,205],})

def avg_step(g):
    print('g = ')
    print(g, '\n')
    s = g[['d1', 'd2']].diff().mean()
    s.index = ['d1_step', 'd2_step']
    print('s = ')
    print(s, '\n')
    return s

df.groupby(['c1', 'c2']).apply(avg_step)
```

The function that you apply gets as an argument the group itself. I've added some `print` statements for you to see what is going on. For the first group, you get

```
g = 
  c1  c2  code   d1   d2
0  a   3     1  100  200
1  a   3     2  101  201
2  a   3     3  102  202 

s = 
d1_step    1.0
d2_step    1.0
dtype: float64
```

For the second, it is

```
g = 
  c1  c2  code   d1   d2
3  b   4     1  103  203
4  b   4     2  104  204
5  b   4     3  105  205 

s = 
d1_step    1.0
d2_step    1.0
dtype: float64
```

If you run the code, you'll see though that the output of the first group is duplicated! That's because pandas executes the given function for the first group twice. The first time it is to see if it can take a fast route or it has to go through the slower one — and discards the output. The second time is the one that returns the result to the aggregation.